# How does DynamoDB internal architecture look like?

Tags: amazon-web-services, indexing, database-design, amazon-dynamodb, b-tree-index

How does the indexing maintained internally?

Does the partition behaves like a binary tree? [How Database B-tree Indexing works - DZone Database](https://dzone.com/articles/database-btree-indexing-in-sqlite)

[The Guts 'n' Glory of Database Internals: B+Tree - DZone Database](https://dzone.com/articles/the-guts-n-glory-of-database-internals-btree)

While partitioning the tables, does the actual value reference is maintained.

Any light on this could be helpful.

Comment: [A Decade of Dynamo: Powering the next wave of high-performance, internet-scale applications - All Things Distributed](https://www.allthingsdistributed.com/2017/10/a-decade-of-dynamo.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [­­Building DynamoDB brick by brick](https://medium.com/@sterling.shrey/building-dynamodb-brick-by-brick-237e0008b698) where I tried to explain Partitioning and other aspects of DynamoDB in depth.