# Internal working of DynamoDB while Querying

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries, key-value-store

How does read query works in dynamoDB? I know that it internally calculates the hash based on the partition key and finds out the in which partition the item is present. After finding the partition how do you find the specific location of the item/record. Does it scan the complete partition for that item. If it scans the complete partition then how is dynamoDB called a key value lookup store?

I have searched for that in AWS Documentation, It's quite fascinating that is not mentioned anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

A query returns all items with a given partition key value, ordered by sort key value. No, it doesn't need to scan the partition to do this because there is an internal index.

See [Data distribution: Partition key and sort key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/HowItWorks.Partitions.html#HowItWorks.Partitions.CompositeKey):

> it stores all the items with the same partition key value physically close together, ordered by sort key value.

I agree that it's [difficult](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58042169/how-does-dynamodb-internal-architecture-look-like) to find any AWS-supplied documentation that confirms that there is a partition-level index on pk+sk or discusses the implementation of the indexing (LSM, B-Tree etc.) Will update this answer if/when I find evidence.

Comment: What if table doesn't have a sort key, then how will it search?
Let say We have Pet's table based on the above doc, Partition1 has different items whose partition keys are "Bird", "Cat" and "Turtle". Since those are different partition keys we can assume these hash values can be different/same. let say for argumentative sake hash values are different then how does search happen in that case?

Comment: There is no 'search' in DynamoDB. There is GetItem, Query, and Scan (and a few other operations, e.g. batch-related). If your items have a simple primary key, i.e. comprising partition key only, then the only way to retrieve multiple items in a single request is to use BatchGetItem and provide the relevant partition keys of Bird, Cat, and Turtle.